# How to print left subtree of Binary Heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, binary, heap, binary-tree

I'm having trouble printing the left subtree of the root in a binary heap. I want to do it recursively but i don't think I am doing it correctly. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
template <class Comparable>
    void BinaryHeap<Comparable> :: printLtSubtree(int i)
    {

            // INSERT CODE for printLtSubtree HERE
            if (i > currentSize)
                    System.exit();
            if (i <= currentSize)
                    cout << array[i];
                    printLtSubtree(i->left);
                    printLtSubtree(i->right);

    }
```

I just want to print out the element if the index is less than currentSize.

This might help:

```
template <class Comparable>
    class BinaryHeap
    {
      public:
        explicit BinaryHeap( int capacity = 100 );

        bool isEmpty( ) const;
        bool isFull( ) const;
        const Comparable & findMin( );

        // const Comparable & findMax( );

    // int Height () const; 
    void printLtSubtree();
        void insert( const Comparable & x );
        void deleteMin( );
        void deleteMin( Comparable & minItem );
        void makeEmpty( );

      private:
        int                currentSize;  // Number of elements in heap
        vector<Comparable> array;        // The heap array

        void buildHeap( );
        void percolateDown( int hole );
        void printLtSubtree (int i);
    };

    #include "BinaryHeap.cpp"
```

Main Function:

```
void FillHeap (BinaryHeap<char>& B);

int main()
{
BinaryHeap<char> PQ(50);

FillHeap (PQ);

PQ.deleteMin();

PQ.printLtSubtree();

return 0;
}

void FillHeap (BinaryHeap<char>& B)
{
B.insert('A');
    B.insert('B');
    B.insert('C');
    B.insert('D');
    B.insert('E');
    B.insert('F');
    B.insert('G');
    B.insert('H');
    B.insert('I');
    B.insert('J');
}
```

Comment: what does currentSize mean?

Comment: `i` isn't a pointer, you can't dereference it with `->`. Why throwing at us code that's incomplete and doesn't even compile?

Comment: Do you realize that the code that removes the minimum element from the binary heap does, in fact, traverse the heap in exactly the same fashion as you need for printing? Look at your `percolateDown()`, it all should be there.